# ASP.NET CORE do not render ViewComponents when the application is part of website

Tags: asp.net-core, iis-6, asp.net-core-viewcomponent

I deployed ASP.NET core 2.2 application to IIS 6. It is working and displays all forms. I have a request to have this application to be part of big website. I copied application to another directory and changed *hostingModel* from ***inprocess*** to ***outofprocess*** in *web.config* file. Now the application can be viewed with other applications, however it does not display any ViewComponents in it. Any advice will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I was using JavaScript to invoke ViewComponents and it was worked good when the web application is stand alone. However, if it is a part of web site it is not working. I did not find the reason, I just set invocation of ViewComponents in Razor page, instead of JavaScript, and it started to work normally.